# R maximum observations for color scheme in a plot

Tags: r, if-statement, colors

I am working with a relatively large dataset (n>1000). I have come across a problem when applying "ifelse" in order to specify different colors in a plot.

With a small selection of data, the specified colors are displayed. When using the large dataset, the colors appear as red and green, no matter which colors I specified. 
So far I have encountered this problem with ggplot2, plotly and condformat (with different data).

E.g.

```
condformat(fullData[1:500,]) %>%
rule_fill_discrete(title, expression = ifelse(start_var == end_var,  "purple", "orange"))
```

works, but

```
condformat(fullData[1:1000,]) %>%
rule_fill_discrete(title, expression = ifelse(start_var == end_var, "purple", "orange"))
```

will display the colors not in orange and purple, but red and green.

I apologize in advance if this is a trivial question, but my google search remained unsuccesful. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`rule_fill_discrete` maps discrete values to colors. If you want to specify which colors are mapped to which values you should use a named vector as the `colours` argument. See this example:

```
library(condformat)
d <- data.frame(title = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"),
                start_var = c(4, 5, 6),
                end_var = c(4, 8, 6))
condformat(d) %>%
  rule_fill_discrete(title,
                     expression = start_var == end_var,
                     colours = c(`TRUE` = "purple", `FALSE` = "orange"))
```

[image: Result of running the given code]